# estou tentando somar dois numeros e salvar o resultado no banco com laravel mais esta dando erro undefined offset

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function somar(Request $req){

    $dados= $req->all();
    $n1=$_POST['n1'];
    $n2=$_POST['n2'];
    $resultado=$n1+$n2;
     Calculo::create([
        'resultado'=> $dados[$resultado], 
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('admin.calculadora');

}
```

Comment: Veja em seu HTML se o input está com atributo name como n1 e n2

Comment: sim ta com os mesmos nomes no html ele ta pegando o resultado até só sei que é alguma coisa que ta faltando ali no array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João,há algumas incoerências no código:

Na primeira linha você armazena em $dados, todos os inputs que veio na requisição.

Porém na segunda e terceira linhas, você não usa o array $dados para extrair seus inputs dele. Sem problemas, até aqui.

Na quarta linha, você armazena em $resultado, o valor da soma $n1 e $n2. Uma variável foi criada ($resultado).

No método create, você solicita um dado que sequer existe no array. O índice $resultado não existe no array $dados. Se você quer inserir $resultados na coluna 'resultado', é só fazer :

```
Calculo::create([
        'resultado'=> $resultado, 
]);
```

Note que você sequer usou o array $dados. Talvez, o fluxo que você procurava era este :

```
$dados = $request->all();
$n1 = $dados['n1'];
$n2 = $dados['n2'];
$resultado = $n1 + $n2;

Calculo::create([
        'resultado'=> $resultado, 
]);
```

Ainda dá pra deixar seu código mais objetivo.

```
$resultado = $request->input('n1') + $request->input('n2');

Calculo::create([
        'resultado'=> $resultado, 
]);
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: valeu mesmo cara me ajudou muito